# Round values in java

Tags: java, rounding

How will I round

1. 1 < value < 1.5 to 1.5
2. 1.5 < value < 2 to 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
double rounded = Math.ceil(number * 2) / 2;
```

Since `Math.ceil()` already returns a double, no need to divide by `2.0d` here. This will work fine as long as you're in the range of integers that can be expressed as doubles without losing precision, but beware if you fall out of that range.

Answer (score 2):

```
public double foo(double x){
  int res = Math.round(x);
  if(res>x) // x > .5
   return res -0.5;
  else 
   return res + 0.5;
}
```

I havent compiled this but this is pseudocode and should work

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 2, use `Math.ceil()`, then divide that result by 2.

Comment: I see Andrew Mao just beat me to it.

Comment: Was about to ask if you copied my answer or you just didn't look :)

Comment: I didn't see your answer when I typed mine.  I don't think the page had refreshed yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public double round(double num)
    {
        double rounded = (int) (num + 0.4999f);
        if(num > rounded)
            return rounded + 0.5;
        else
            return rounded;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
double numberGrade = 2.5;
Math.ceil(numberGrade);
```

Comment: I suggest you recheck what you've posted, before your answer gets downvoted.

Comment: whoops im sorry, it should be double or float

Comment: but that won't do what the question asked for. the original poster needs to round up to the next half. yours rounds up to the next integer.

Comment: Hmm Then i guess simple branching like @smk will do;