# Generating a random double integer

Tags: java, prng

How can I pick a random number from the following set:

- All positive integers that can be represented exactly by a double precision floating point number (i.e. a Java `double`).

**Distribution**

In my particular use case, I don't need uniform distribution. I am, however, academically interested in such a solution. Also, uniform could be interpreted in (at least) 2 different ways:

- The distribution is uniform in [0, Double.MAX_VALUE].
- The probability of picking each possible value is equal.

Comment: Where is your tried code ?

Comment: What do you mean by exactly ?

Comment: what do you mean by `exactly by a double precision floating point number`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643067/range-of-integers-that-can-be-expressed-precisely-as-floats-doubles

Comment: It's quite an interesting set, however! The set contains: `1, 2, 12345, 1.2345e100`; and doesn't contain `1234567891234567891234`

Comment: Suresh: What I tried is `Math.round(random.nextDouble())`, forgetting that `nextDouble` returns between 0 and 1, not all possible double values. Emrys: Given the number as a `long`, that `number == (long)((double)number)`

Comment: Why all the downvotes? In my opinion the question is both interesting (if perhaps not very practical) and sufficiently precise...

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom I don't think downvoters have understood the question.

Comment: Do you need to be able to draw every number in the set with equal probability? If so then this is a *very* interesting question. Else you could draw a double, multiply by Double.MAX_VALUE and test that result to see it if it's an integer.

Comment: So what is it? (1) uniformly from the set or (2) such that the resulting distribution is uniform? Do let me know if the difference is not obvious to you.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Though I may occasionally use the wrong terms, the difference is clear. I don't care either way, this question is purely academical now. I've found that in my use case it's easier to just generate a random 48 bit unsigned integer (`nextLong() & 0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF`), since that's a large enough space and all values can be represented by a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that doubles are 64 bits you could generate 8 bytes of randomness and use NIO to get the corresponding double, this should provide full coverage I think... however it wouldn't produce a uniform distribution.

```
Random random = new Random();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
random.nextBytes(buffer);

System.out.println(Math.abs(Math.round(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getDouble())));
```

I've been reminding myself how doubles are represented in Java by looking at [double 64 binary layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), there are 11 bits for the exponent and 52 bits for the fraction. I think an answer that provides a uniform distribution would be pretty tricky

Comment: I did think of something like that. Of course, you'd need to apply `round` and `abs` to make it a positive integer. I don't think the distribution would be very uniform. That's not a problem in my current use case, but it hurts the perfectionist inside :)

Comment: If you study the spec. for IEEE 754 you could combine that with my approach... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fact that the resulting distribution is not uniform.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of the following untested methods.

**The distribution is uniform in [0, Double.MAX_VALUE].**

- Generate a random `BigInteger` between 0 and Double.MAX_VALUE ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20java.util.Random))).
- Apply `doubleValue()`

**The probability of picking each possible value is equal.**

- Create a buffer of 64 bits.
- Set the sign to positive.
- Set the exponent randomly between 1 and 1023.
- Fill the rest (the fraction) with random bits.
- If the number is not normalized (e.g. it's 200 * 2, where the normalized version is 400 * 1), discard it and try again.